# Root Lenovo vibe p1ma40 with Lollipop 5.1

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rooting, root-access, rom-flashing, lenovo

I'm trying to root Lenovo vibe p1ma40 with Lollipop 5.1 this particular device since last couple of day, without any success. So I need your help to do this, or not this particular device but it would be good if there will be generic solution for root of android device.

Below is list of techniques that I've already tried :

1) KingoRoot, and other apps - seems they are under development for this particular device.

2) SP Flash Tool([link](http://www.cyberkey.in/how-to-root-lenovo-vibe-p1m/)) - device go to charging mode after step-8.

3) Fast boot([link](http://www.techolaty.com/33952/how-to-root-lenovo-vibe-p1m.html)- METHOD 1) - command **fastboot boot recovery.img** gives error as - FAILED (remote: download for partition 'boot' is not allowed)
**or** - command **fastboot flash recovery recovery.img** gives error as - FAILED (remote: download for partition 'recovery' is not allowed)

4) New Flashing Commands([link](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/11/15/psa-unlocking-the-nexus-6p-bootloader-requires-the-new-flashing-command-likely-to-become-common-for-many-devices-in-the-future/)) - command **fastboot flashing unlock_critical** gives unknown command error.

Any help would be highly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unlock the bootloader first using the command: `fastboot oem unlock` (Note: Unlocking bootloader formats the User data (/data partition). So make a backup of apps/settings first).
Then flash/boot the recovery :)

Comment: That [third link](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/11/15/psa-unlocking-the-nexus-6p-bootloader-requires-the-new-flashing-command-likely-to-become-common-for-many-devices-in-the-future/) is specifically about Nexus 6P, so why are you using them on your non-Nexus 6P? The instructions there are bound to fail on your device.

Comment: @Gokul - Tried this command too. Even after execution of this command and then following method 3 as describe above gives error. And no this command doesn't format any data.

Comment: @Firelord - I've installed latest adb  with fastboot for Ubuntu and linux while in Ubuntu these commands are not displaying but in Windows these commanda are diplaying in help.

Comment: So I thought if it has something to do with android lollipop 5.1 then let me give it a try.

Comment: Just to make sure, did you do this step: [click on checkbox recovery and browse to the extracted files and locate recovery.img](http://www.techolaty.com/33952/how-to-root-lenovo-vibe-p1m.html) for your technique 2 ?

Comment: Yes Gokul I did that also.

Comment: Did you [install VCOM drivers](http://thetechnolyte.blogspot.gr/2014/04/installing-vcom-drivers-in-windows-81.html) in your computer (for doing that SP Flash Tool method) ? Where I found this hint: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=64339913&postcount=2

Comment: @Gokul .. Really really thanks mate. You're life saviour. Please put your comment as an answer with some details, so I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: Also I've downloaded "recovery.img" from technique 2 (http://www.cyberkey.in/how-to-root-lenovo-vibe-p1m)(He has also updated same  for VCOM drivers) is it reliable?

Comment: @Chitrang Yeah I think the recovery is OK. He has given screenshots also. So, go ahead :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [the technique 2 that you have listed](http://www.cyberkey.in/how-to-root-lenovo-vibe-p1m/), you have to install the [**USB VCOM drivers** in your computer](http://thetechnolyte.blogspot.gr/2014/04/installing-vcom-drivers-in-windows-81.html) so that [SP Flash Tool](http://spflashtool.com/) can detect your phone and to enter Download Mode via the USB VCOM port.

> This action will add the following drivers in to the operating system:
>
> **MediaTek DA USB VCOM Port**
>   **MediaTek PreLoader USB VCOM Port** – for transferring the firmware to your device
>   **MTK USB DEBUG Port**
>   **MTK USB Modem Port**
>   **MTK USB Port** – for transfering PreLoader to your device (and recovery in case of bad or corrupt firmware)
>
> Source:
>   http://laurentiumihet.ro/technology/windows-10-mtk-vcom-usb-drivers-for-32-64-bit-drivers-installation-tutorial/

This should definitely work and [help you root your phone](http://www.cyberkey.in/how-to-root-lenovo-vibe-p1m/).

---

For [your technique 3 (using fastboot)](http://www.techolaty.com/33952/how-to-root-lenovo-vibe-p1m.html), I think you get the error:

> FAILED (remote: download for partition 'recovery' is not allowed)

Because you need to unlock the bootloader to flash the recovery.
This varies a little bit for different phones.
The most common command to unlock bootloader is:

> fastboot oem unlock

Before doing this, do this: (this might be required sometimes)
1. Go to settings -> About Phone -> Tap on "Build Version" until it shows developer, may be 7 times.
2. In Settings -> Developer Options -> **Enable OEM Unlock**.

After doing this, still if you're unable to unlock the bootloader or flash recovery using fastboot, I would recommend you to seek further help from the [Lenovo Forums](https://forums.lenovo.com/).

Comment: Hi @Gokul any help for this http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135607/how-to-resolve-boot-loop-problem-on-android-pumpkinx-10-1-tablet

Answer (score 0):

No need of any other methods. Just use kingroot. Its best. It didn't work for me for about 3 times. 4th time it worked.
Use latest kingroot app